# A problem of proof in integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Please help me solve this problem.

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^1 f(t) e^{-at}dt = 0$, $\forall a \in (0,1)$. Then show that $f \equiv 0$. [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03HtJ.jpg)

My initial ideas were , since the exponential function is always positive so if we can somehow establish the fact that f is non-negetive then we are done. But I cannot proceed after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: Differentiate the equation $\int_0^{1}f(t)e^{-at} dt=0$ w.r.t. $a$ repeatedly to get $\int_0^{1}t^{n}f(t)e^{-at}dt=0$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $a \in (0,1)$. Let $a \to 0+$ to get $\int_0^{1} t^{n}f(t)dt=0$ for all $n \geq 0$. This implies $f \equiv 0$ by an application of Weiertsrass Theorem.

[Surely differentiation under the integral and taking the limit as $a \to 0+$ require justifications but I am assuming that you are familiar with DCT].

Comment: Thanks for this hint.